# How is google call screen streaming audio to an incoming call?

Tags: android, audio, kernel, audio-streaming, incoming-call

I have been trying to stream an on-device audio file to an incoming call, I am not able to achieve that. but it looks [google call screen](https://youtu.be/SHKco5Ax1DE) is having no problem streaming audio to an incoming call.

I just wanted to understand how are they achieving that, if it is fundamentally not possible?

Comment: The link to the video doesn't appear to have streaming audio, just Google intercepting the call and reporting if it is a spam number or transcribing incoming speech.

Comment: Google assistant does send a response to the caller

Comment: https://youtu.be/SHKco5Ax1DE this video shows what the caller is hearing